# Debugging in multi threading environment in c sharp .net

Tags: multithreading, shared-memory, visual-studio-debugging

I have a huge multi threaded windows application code. I have a object in shared memory which is updated by multiple threads in different processes. I am unable to find who is updating the property of shared object. How can i find which thread/method is updating the property of object in shared memory.

Comment: You need to write your code in a thread-safe way. At the very least you need to use locks to ensure only one thread can modify that object. Better options are to use thread-safe classes like ConcurrentQueue, Lazy<T> etc.

Comment: If you simply want to know which code modified your property, put a breakpoint in the setter. That won't make the code thread-safe though

Comment: This is legacy code written 20 years back. Looking ways if visual studio can provide a way of call stack kind between different processes. currently it shows external code..but not sure from which external code this process is called.

Comment: Can [this tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/dd998398(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) help to monitor threads in VS.

Comment: @Amarnath you still haven't explained what you want. Visual Studio already offers a lot  of support for multithreaded debugging, like the Parallel Stacks and Threads Windows, Intellitrace and more. There's [an entire section on this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-parallel-stacks-window?view=vs-2019) in the docs site. [Concurrency Visualizer](https://medium.com/@paul.freedman19/gaining-intuition-on-multi-threading-with-visual-studio-concurrency-visualizer-40414548de7c) is a very useful tool for Visual Studio 2015, 2017

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i am completely new to multi threading debugging. What i want exactly is : i have muli threaded window application where mulitple processes are involved and finally updates UI. I would like to have a call stack across processes across multiple threads.Also would like to see a kind of call stack what all methods of different processes are involved in updating UI through visual studio.let me know if it is clear.

Comment: That's what the [Parallel Stacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-parallel-stacks-window?view=vs-2019) window does.